# How to update a has_many association field without losing existing items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form, has-many

I am using rails 5.1

I have a model named 'Pitch', which has a many-to-many relationship with skills. (I am using 'has_many through' method for this)

Now, each skill belongs_to a member.

So, while creating a pitch I want to allow the user to be able to select specific skills for each of his team member. And then have the pitch show all skills together.

My challenge is this,

When I add a skill/skills for a specific member and update pitch, the skill/skills previously added are deleted.

Here is my code in '_member.html.erb' partial, which is called on show page for pitch.

```
<%= simple_form_for @pitch do |f| %>    

<%= f.association :skills, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Skill.all.where(:member_id => @member.id) %>

<%end%>
```

As I add skills for the each member, the skills previously added are deleted.

What can be the issue here, and how do I fix it?

Please let me know if the question is not clear enough.
Thanks.

Comment: please show models, server log on submit, controller p

Comment: Are Skills kind of like a list that can be used across members and pitches?, i.e., are Skills created when you create a member or when creating a member do you select from a list of Skills? Can multiple members have the same skill?

Comment: @inveterateliterate Skills are added by each member and each skill belongs_to a specific member.